# How to capture crashes if the app crashes on launch

Tags: ios, crashlytics

I currently have an issue with my app where it's crashing on launch in some cases for some users in the field, but not in-house. In this case, the whole app shuts down before Crashlytics gets a chance to submit its crash report. How do I avoid this? The Crashlytics delegate protocol doesn't seem to support anything useful in this case - I tried turning off the asynchronous submission functionality, but it did not help. What's the best solution to capture crashes that happen immediately on start-up?

Edit: I am talking about capturing crashes from users in the field, not from my own device.

Comment: did u try set `All Exceptions` breakpoint? or you can check the console see what it said

Comment: I am talking about capturing crashes from users in the field, not from my own device.

Answer (score -1):

XCode->(Window menu -> Organizer, or Cmd-Shift-2.) Find your device in the left sidebar, then select “device logs”.

Comment: I am talking about capturing crashes from users in the field, not from my own device.

Answer (score -1):

A tool for detecting and repairting continuous launch crash of iOS App

https://github.com/liuslevis/GYBootingProtection